# How could I make an API request from front-end through server so my API key wouldn't be visible to the end-user?

Tags: javascript, api, backend

I've researched that if I'd like to hide my API keys I have to do the requests through back-end.

What would be the best way to hide my API keys?
And please don't suggest using environment variables, I'd like to know best practice to make an API request through server to the API's server.

Comment: If you down voted my answer @Bix it's good practice to explain why.

Comment: You mean you don't want to put the API key in the code which is visible to the browser? In that case then yes you have to make a request to your server which then makes a request to the API and passes the response back. Therefore the API key can be stored securely on the server. It's not an uncommon scenario. Hiding the key is simple essentially - don't make it available in any file which could be downloaded via a http request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, and against your request not to suggest it, ENV Variables are an industry standard. By doing this as such:

1. You don't have to commit your API Keys to a code repository
2. You can change them on the fly and restart your system to pick them up, or code in a manner that picks them up fresh every time they are needed
3. They don't end up in your UI code visible to the world, and subsequently visible in every request you send.

One other method would be to store credentials values in a database somewhere. But you have the chicken/egg scenario there. Where are you going to store your DB credentials so you can access the DB? Can't go in the DB because you wouldn't be able to read them. You'd have to put them in an environment variable or, commit the DB credentials in the code repository - and that isn't best practice by any stretch.

Comment: But aren't environment variables visilbe? I believe it was stated by React somewhere that it's visible via developer console (canno't find it anymore). Mr JK up there thinks the question is stupid, though there are no questions that I could find on topic how to hide api keys without .env..

Comment: ENV variables don't exist in UIs except at time of minification/build/etc to set certain flags. Environment variables are common on server side projects, and unless you've made access to your servers public, which is bad practice, then no - they are not visible.

Comment: Alright thank you. Btw, I didn't downvote. Must've been JK.